# Unable to reshow a sheet if triggered from navigationBar

Tags: ios, swiftui

please help!

I have a simple test code below, to display a sheet when a button is pressed. The issue is when I place the button inside a `.toolbar` and for the first press the sheet is shown as expected. However, if I were to dismiss the sheet and press the button again, nothing happens and no error is printed out in the console.

If i were to place the button at `.bottomBar` or withing `VStack` everything works as expected, I can show and dismiss the sheet multiple times.

I am using Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100) and running on iPhone 13 (iOS 15.2)simulator. Haven't tried running on a real device. [Video Example](https://youtu.be/BjFsoi_xMpU)

I've been trying to understand what is happening for 2 days and still have no idea what is the cause.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Show Sheet") {
                    showingSheet.toggle()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Show once?!") {
                        showingSheet.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
               Text("Drag to dismiss")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Solution**:
Press and hold button and then drag it down just a little bit (other directions are no no) till the button is registered as clicked and .sheet will be presented as intended. Ridiculous :D

Comment: Using same version of Xcode, same iOS version, same simulator and I could not try reproducing your issue. I tried a new project with pasting your code in and also tried with one of my existing projects. Any of the two buttons seem to work correctly; a new screen appears as a sheet which can be dismissed, this pattern can be used any number of times. Maybe restart your computer, restart Simulator, clean build folder... Or there might be something completely else going on...

Comment: Could not replicate your issue. 
The code works well for me using macos 12.2 Beta, Xcode 13.2, 
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real devices and on iPhone 13 simulator. Maybe still a problem with xcode 13.2.1

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue on the simulator but not on a real device. Perhaps it's a bug on the simulator. Stick to running it on a real device.

Comment: @Anwuna You wouldn't believe what I had to do in order for it to work properly on simulator for every 2nd click. Basically, press and hold button and then drag it down just a little bit (other directions are no no) till the button is registered as clicked and  .sheet will be presented as intended. Ridiculous :D